# Wild Cards * in If Else Statements - Batch Scripting

Tags: batch-file, wildcard

I have to match a file pattern in else block in a bat file.
*abc*20170202*.txt

Below is a example where I need this:

```
IF EXIST abc.txt (
ECHO "abc File exists"
TIMEOUT 5
) else (
echo *abc*20170202*.txt>> download.txt
echo File printed successful..
PAUSE
)
```

it does not consider * as wild character in here.
Please guide how this can be achieved

**Edit**

Below is a example where I need this:

```
@ECHO OFF
for /f "tokens=2*" %%a in ('net user "%USERNAME%" /domain ^| find /i "Full Name"') do set DisplayName=%%b
IF EXIST ~%~n0%~x0.loc SET /p dname=<~%~n0%~x0.loc
IF EXIST ~%~n0%~x0.loc (
ECHO *****************************************************
ECHO Script is already running by User : %dname%  
ECHO *****************************************************
TIMEOUT 5
) else (
ECHO %DisplayName% > ~%~n0%~x0.loc
echo cd /abcdata/contrl>> download.txt
echo prompt>> download.txt
echo mget *abc*20170202*.txt>> download.txt
echo bye>> download.txt
ftp -s:download.txt xx.xx.xx.xx
REM "Replace xx.xx.xx.xx with a IP address"
del /Q download.txt
echo File downloded successful..
TIMEOUT 5
DEL ~%~n0%~x0.loc
)
```

At line `echo mget *abc*20170202*.txt>> download.txt`
it does not considers * as wild character and rather normal text.
It is supposed to match 10 files, however it doesn't.

Below is the log I receive on running this

```
Connected to xx.xx.xx.xx.
220 (vsFTPd x.x.x)
User (xx.xx.xx.xx:(none)):
331 Please specify the password.

230 Login successful.
ftp> cd /abcdata/contrl
250 Directory successfully changed.
ftp> prompt
Interactive mode Off .
ftp> mget *abc*20170202*.txt
200 Switching to ASCII mode.
ftp> bye
221 Goodbye.
File downloded successful..
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Please guide how this can be done.

Comment: What do you expect to appear inside download.txt?  If it's the contents of all files matching *abc*.txt use "type" instead of "echo"?  if it's a list of filenames you'll need something else.

Comment: Its not the full script, I have removed some parts of the actual script and focused only on part were I see the problem. ,  actual line is "echo mget *abc*20170202*.txt>> download.txt". I just want to find a way to match the said pattern  *abc*20170202*.txt  in file list

Comment: What is `*abc*20170202*.txt` or `abc*20170202.txt` supposed to be matching? What exactly are you wanting to do if file `abc.txt` does not exist? Please provide full and proper answers and please edit the code in your question with the actual commands you are trying, _do not substuitute them for ones which you guess may do something similar_.

Comment: I have edited the question with all the script , removing the ip. please suggest a solution, thank you

Comment: Please do not edit a question to such an extent that it invalidates an existing answer.  Question after edit is totally different from question before edit.  Edit was undone.  (And, I now have to go to "meta.stackoverflow.com" to ask what to do in such cases.)

Comment: yes I understand the ethics of editing the question. :) . I have not come to a solution yet. Any help would be greatly appreciated.. @MikeNakis

Comment: what happens if you ***manually*** connect to your ftp server, cd into `/abcdata/contrl` and type the command `mget *abc*20170202*.txt` ?

Comment: it works perfectly that way. Line 11-18 is the initial script that worked fine for quite some time. I am updating the script to ensure one instance is run at a time and I am using a lock file to have this implemented. the command `mget *abc*20170202*.txt ` stopped working after I put it in if else block.

Answer (score 1):

`echo` does not work the way you think it does.

Try this:

```
dir /s/b *abc*20170202*.txt>> download.txt
```

Comment: it works for me.  I do not know what kind of problem you are having.  Does it work outside of `if...else...` for you?

Comment: the updated question is a totally different question.